# How to remove a XSSFSingleXmlCell with Apache POI 5.2.3?

Tags: java, excel, xml, apache-poi

Similarly to this post, [How to read/write XML maps from/in excel with Apache POI in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693029/how-to-read-write-xml-maps-from-in-excel-with-apache-poi-in-java?newreg=4416dffe03ab4c61a75a7c63043a73a0) I want to read/write XML maps from/to Excel with Apache POI. I am able to create multiple XML maps, but now I want to remove them.

Here I have an example with two XML maps:
[Two XML maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE17j.png)

Removing the schema and map is not the problem, but I have the requirement that specific user roles may drag the XML Map elements to an Excel file and save the file. Thus, I want to be able to remove the schema, map and **related XML cells** for a single data structure.

I am able to remove the related tables (`XSSFTable`), but I could not find out how to remove the single XML cells (`XSSFSingleXmlCell`).

In the below code I tried to delete the associated `POIXMLDocumentPart` with reflection similar to this post [How to remove all formulas from workbook with Java POI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46391336/22082655). In principle, I am able to delete XML cells with the `removeRelation` in the code below, but the affected `POIXMLDocumentPart` object contains all of the single XML cells in the Excel file. This would also delete the related cells from the other XML map.

The code using Apache POI 5.2.3:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.MapInfo;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SingleXmlCells;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFMap;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.XSSFSingleXmlCell;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTMap;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTMapInfo;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSchema;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@Log4j2
public class RemoveXmlMap {

    public static boolean removeXmlZuordnung(XSSFWorkbook workbook, MapInfo mapInfo, String schemaId) {
        if (removeSchema(mapInfo, schemaId)) {
            return removeMap(workbook, mapInfo, schemaId);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean removeSchema(MapInfo mapInfo, String schemaId) {
        CTMapInfo ctMapInfo = mapInfo.getCTMapInfo();
        int index = -1;
        List<CTSchema> schemas = ctMapInfo.getSchemaList();
        for (int i = 0; i < schemas.size(); i++) {
            if (schemaId.equals(schemas.get(i).getID())) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        ctMapInfo.removeSchema(index);
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean removeMap(XSSFWorkbook workbook, MapInfo mapInfo, String schemaId) {
        CTMapInfo ctMapInfo = mapInfo.getCTMapInfo();
        int index = -1;
        List<CTMap> ctMaps = ctMapInfo.getMapList();
        for (int i = 0; i < ctMaps.size(); i++) {
            if (schemaId.equals(ctMaps.get(i).getSchemaID())) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        CTMap ctMap = ctMapInfo.getMapArray(index);
        XSSFMap xssfMap = new XSSFMap(ctMap, mapInfo);
        removeXmlMappingsForMap(workbook, mapInfo, xssfMap);
        ctMapInfo.removeMap(index);
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean removeXmlMappingsForMap(XSSFWorkbook workbook, MapInfo mapInfo, XSSFMap xssfMap) {
        if (!removeXmlMappingsForSingleCells(workbook, mapInfo, xssfMap)) {
            return false;
        }
        return removeXmlMappingsForTables(workbook, xssfMap);
    }

    private static boolean removeXmlMappingsForSingleCells(XSSFWorkbook workbook, MapInfo mapInfo, XSSFMap xssfMap) {
        Set<POIXMLDocumentPart> documentPartForSingleXmlCells = getPoiXmlDocumentPartForSingleCells(mapInfo, xssfMap.getCtMap());
        for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            for (POIXMLDocumentPart documentPart : documentPartForSingleXmlCells) {
                if (documentPart instanceof SingleXmlCells singleXMLCells) {
                    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
                    List<XSSFSingleXmlCell> xssfSingleXmlCells = singleXMLCells.getAllSimpleXmlCell();
                    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(sheet.getRelationId(documentPart)) && !xssfSingleXmlCells.isEmpty()) {
                        if (!removeRelation(sheet, documentPart)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean removeXmlMappingsForTables(XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFMap xssfMap) {
        for (XSSFTable table : xssfMap.getRelatedTables()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
                if (sheet.getTables().contains(table)) {
                    sheet.removeTable(table);
                    if (sheet.getTables().contains(table)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Based on XSSFMap.getRelatedSingleXMLCell
    private static Set<POIXMLDocumentPart> getPoiXmlDocumentPartForSingleCells(MapInfo mapInfo, CTMap ctMap) {
        Set<POIXMLDocumentPart> poiXmlDocumentParts = new HashSet<>();

        int sheetNumber = mapInfo.getWorkbook().getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int i = 0; i < sheetNumber; i++) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = mapInfo.getWorkbook().getSheetAt(i);
            for (POIXMLDocumentPart p : sheet.getRelations()) {
                if (p instanceof SingleXmlCells singleXMLCells) {
                    for (XSSFSingleXmlCell cell : singleXMLCells.getAllSimpleXmlCell()) {
                        if (cell.getMapId() == ctMap.getID()) {
                            poiXmlDocumentParts.add(p);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return poiXmlDocumentParts;
    }

    private static boolean removeRelation(XSSFSheet sheet, POIXMLDocumentPart poiXmlDocumentPart) {
        try {
            Method removeRelation = POIXMLDocumentPart.class.getDeclaredMethod("removeRelation", POIXMLDocumentPart.class, boolean.class);
            removeRelation.setAccessible(true);
            Boolean success = (Boolean) removeRelation.invoke(sheet, poiXmlDocumentPart, true);
            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(success)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            log.error("Could not execute method 'removeRelation'!");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to delete single XML cells without affecting other XML maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to deal with such kinds of requirements?**

All Office Open XML files, as `*.xlsx` too, are ZIP archives. So one can simply unzip them and have a look into the structure. Doing so for a `*.xlsx` file having XML maps to single cells, one will find `/xl/tables/tableSingleCells[n].xml` for each sheet having single cells mapped to XML. The root element of the XML in those files is `singleXmlCells`. In terms of the Office Open XML file structure, there is a document part `/xl/tables/tableSingleCells[n].xml` having XML to store the XML mapping for single cells.

**Is Apache POI supporting this kind of document part?**

In Apache POI 5.2.3, there is [SingleXmlCells](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/SingleXmlCells.html), which is exactly that document part. But there is not any getter to get objects of that class already. But each document part extends `org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart` which has a method `getRelations()` to get all related parts. So one can get the `SingleXmlCells` from `XSSFSheet` by looping through all related parts of given `XSSFSheet` until one finds instance of `SingleXmlCells`.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SingleXmlCells;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class ExcelRemoveCellFromSingleXmlCells {
        
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (
       XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelWithXMLMapSingleCells.xlsx"));
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./ExcelWithXMLMapSingleCellsNew.xlsx")
       ) {
           
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.cloneSheet(0);
   for (org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart relatedPart : sheet.getRelations()) {
    System.out.println(relatedPart.getClass());
    if (relatedPart instanceof org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SingleXmlCells) {
     SingleXmlCells singleXmlCellsTable = (SingleXmlCells)relatedPart;
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSingleXmlCells ctSingleXmlCells = singleXmlCellsTable.getCTSingleXMLCells();
     System.out.println(ctSingleXmlCells);
    }
   }
   
   workbook.write(out);
  } 
 }
}
```

**Does `SingleXmlCells` support removing single `XSSFSingleXmlCell`s?**

No. But it supports getting the XML object `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSingleXmlCells` using method `getCTSingleXMLCells()`.

**What does that `CTSingleXmlCells` support?**

There is no API documentation for `org.openxmlformats.schemas.*` classes public available. But one can download the sources of `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.3` (for example from here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml-full/5.2.3/). Then one can do `javadoc` from those sources to create a API documentation.

There you will find the method `removeSingleXmlCell​(int i)` in `CTSingleXmlCells`, which "Removes the ith "singleXmlCell" element".